# AWK issue using unix scripts

Tags: awk, text-formatting

I have this file

```
AK3*BPS*2
AK4*8*0510*1
AK3*RMT*12
AK4*1*0128*7*CR
```

and I want this output

```
BPS 2  1
RMT 12 7 CR
```

I am using this command

```
awk -F* '$1=="AK3" { print $2, $3 } "\c" ($1=="AK4" { print $4, $5 }' $FileHome/badfile_$session_num.txt >>  $FileHome/input_output_record.txt
```

but i am getting this result

```
BPS 2
1
RMT 12
7 CR
```

Any hint will be appreciated

Comment: What's that `\c` about? You seem to be missing a `)` somewhere...

Comment: What happens if you have a line starting with `AK3` following another one with `AK3`?

Answer (score 0):

Plain `print` adds a newline (the output record separator), but `printf` doesn't, so we can use that on the `AK3` case with an explicit separator between the fields. In the `AK4` case, we want a field separator before the first field, and the simplest way to get that is to print an empty field first.

```
$ awk -F\* '$1=="AK3" { printf "%s", $2 OFS $3 } $1=="AK4" { print "", $4, $5 }' < input 
BPS 2 1 
RMT 12 7 CR
```

This is easily converted to giving tab-spaced output, just add `-vOFS='\t'` in the beginning of the command line.

Though if you want fixed-width columns, it's probably easiest to use `printf` and width settings on the `%s` format:

```
$ awk -F\* '$1=="AK3" { printf "%-3s %-2s", $2, $3 } $1=="AK4" { printf " %-1s %s\n", $4, $5 }' < input
BPS 2  1 
RMT 12 7 CR
```

Over-long fields will still extend, unless you give the maximum field width too, with e.g. `%-3.3s`, and this will produce broken output if the input lines are not in correct order.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

1. The last two fields of each `AK3` line, followed by
2. Fields four and five from the `AK4` line (field five may be missing).

```
$ awk -F '*' '/^AK3/ { printf("%s\t%s", $2, $3) } /^AK4/ { printf("\t%s\t%s\n", $4, $5) }' data.in
BPS     2       1
RMT     12      7       CR
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to directly control the output record separator(ORS)

```
$ awk -F'*' '$1=="AK3"{ORS=OFS; print $2, $3} $1=="AK4"{ORS=RS; print $4, $5}' ip.txt
BPS 2 1 
RMT 12 7 CR
```

- by default, output field separator(OFS) is single space
- and input record separator(RS) is newline

This is easy to modify for different OFS and also shows empty field

```
$ awk -F'*' -v OFS=',' '$1=="AK3"{ORS=OFS; print $2, $3} $1=="AK4"{ORS=RS; print $4, $5}' ip.txt
BPS,2,1,
RMT,12,7,CR
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
awk -F '*' '{
    printf "%s %s", $2, $3
    getline
    for (i=4; i<=NF; i++) printf " %s", $i
    print ""
}' file | column -t
```

```
BPS  2   1
RMT  12  7  CR
```

With plain bash:

```
while IFS='*' read -r a1 b1 c1; IFS='*' read -r a2 b2 c3 rest
do
    echo "$b1 $c1 ${rest//\*/ }"
done < file
```

Comment: I'm assuming there are always pairs of lines.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for all the answers I tried all of them and I always got the result that I was expecting. Amazing ! help

Comment: lol. Give a fun puzzle to a bunch of nerds, you'll get a lot of responses.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the result by below commands

---

```
sed -n '1~2p' testfile.txt| awk -F "*" '{print $2,$3}'  >> op.txt
sed -n '2~2p' testfile.txt | awk -F "*" '{print $4,$5}' >> op.txt

sed -n '1~2p' op.txt |sed "N;s/\n/ /g" |awk '{print $0"\n"}'; sed -n '2~2p' op.txt| sed "N;s/\n/ /g"
```

---

Output

---

BPS 2 1

RMT 12 7 CR

---

---